# How to use PyQt5 in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, pyqt, pyqt5

Is there possible to use PyQt5 in Visual Studio 2015?
I installed PyQt and created python project. I get an error.

> No module named 'PyQt5'
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the
>   program may be safely continued.

What do I have to do?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hello world")
    window.setCentralWidget(button)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What Python/PyQt version did you install, and how? Does it work when launching Python from the commandline?

Comment: @the-compiler PyQt5-5.5.1-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.5.1-x32. Python - 3.5 but PyQt installed also python 3.4. It do work when I launch Python from the commandline. It also works in Visual Studio without PyQt use.

Comment: The PyQt installer won't install Python, so that must've been something else. But if you installed PyQt for Python 3.4 (it isn't available as an installer for 3.5 yet), you'll need to run 3.4 as well. I'm guessing you are running 3.4 on the commandline, but 3.5 inside visual studio (you could print `sys.version` and `sys.executable` to find out)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In "Solution Explorer" choose "References"->"Add Reference"->"Browse"- tab, where select *.pyd files in (Python installation folder)\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4.
Then in code one can use something like this: "from Qt import * "